# How does type conversion and integer promotion work for stdint.h?

Tags: c, integer-promotion, stdint, conversion-rank

In C, I understand type conversions, integer promotion, casting, etc. for standard types, but how do the stdint.h types factor into this?

For type rankings, the rules state:

- No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same representation.
- The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type, if any.

So assuming an int is 32 bits, does this mean `int > int32_t = uint32_t > short int` in the rankings?

Also, are the stdint.h types also subject to integer promotion? For example if I try to add a signed char to a uint32_t, they will both get promoted to unsigned ints?

Comment: Interesting question, but in practice all `stdint.h` types are usually just aliases of the built-`int` types. So `int` will be the same as `int32_t`, which is clearly contradicting the first bullet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: no.  Since `int32_t` is usually defined with a typedef like this

```
typedef int int32_t;
```

it is the same as `int` and will have the same rank as `int`.

To answer the second question: yes.  Integer promotion still applies.  The types defined in stdint.h behave just like the types they are aliases of.

By the way, to be more confident in how your compiler behaves, you can test all of these things in your compiler by writing invalid code like this and carefully looking at the error message, which will (if you have a good compiler) reveal the type of the expression on the right hand side:

```
void * x = (signed char)-1 + (uint32_t)0;
```

Comment: I guess the question is how does it comply with the standard.

Comment: At some stage in the compilation process, on a typical PC, `int` and `int32_t` are the *same* type, so they have the same rank, and any rules in the standard talking about different types will apply.

Comment: Again, this is in practice. But it should be somehow allowed/mandated by the standard.

Comment: Section 6.7.7 (Type Definitions) of C99 (N1124) says: "A typedef declaration does not introduce a new type, only a synonym for the type so specified."

Comment: the standard doesn't state that stdint types are aliases of standard types. They may be implemented differently, unless I am missing something.

Comment: I get what you're saying, you're saying it's not a new type, so not a new rank, which makes sense. I thought an int just had to be at least a certain size, where int32_t was exactly a specific size, so they could be different sizes, so different rank. So if they're the same size, they're the same rank, but different size = different rank?

Comment: Yeah, if two signed integer types are different sizes, they must also be different types, and would need to have a different rank thanks to that rule you found in the standard.  By the way, `int` is usually the same as `int16_t` or `int32_t` in my experience, even on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: I used your compiler trick with gcc and it converted everything like you said. I also looked in /usr/include/bits/types.h and turns out they are in fact typedefs. Thanks for the help. Now I just need to figure out if uint32_t is always guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits always.

Comment: @user1801359 "uint32_t is always guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits always" is true.  If an implementation cannot do it, then this _optional_ type is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard

> — The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank
> of any extended integer type with the same width.

The exact integer types for 2's complement representation are defined as tyoedef aliases of standard integer types.

From the C Standard (7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types)

> 3. ...and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement
>    representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

So this relational when the type int has 32 bits (for 2's complement representation)

```
int > int32_t = uint32_t > short int
```

is correct except that the relation `int > int32_t` provided that the type `int32_t` is an alias name for the type `int` introduced by a typedef declaration..

> Also, are the stdint.h types also subject to integer promotion? For
> example if I try to add a signed char to a uint32_t, they will both
> get promoted to unsigned ints?

Here the object of the type `unsigned char` is promoted to the type `int` and the object of the type `uint32_t` is promoted to the type `unsigned int` (provided that `int` has 32-bits) due to the integer promotions

From the C Standard

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
> by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
> otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
> integer promotions. 58) All other types are unchanged by the integer
> promotions.

And then the object of the type `int` is converted to the type `unsigned int` due to the usual arithmetic conversions.

From the C Standard (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
> corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

Pay attention to then the name `uint32_t` can be an alias for the type `unsigned int` introduced by a typedef declaration. In this case `uint32_t` is the same type as `unsigned int`.

Comment: is mere typedefing if `int` type changing it's rank?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Typedefing does not changes changes rank because typedef does not introduce a new type.

Comment: Then how can the tank of `int32_t` be different from `int` in case one is the alias if the other?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is it written i n the Standard that uingt32_t is an alias for unsigned int?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have updated my answer. It is interesting to know whether can an implementation define int32_t as an alias for long provided that the type long has 32-bits as in Windows?:)

Comment: It is not, that's the problem, no?

Comment: @EugeneSh. In fact neither prevents an implementation to define int32_t as an alias for long that also has 32 bits.

Comment: My point is that on one hand the standard seemingly implies that two different types should have different ranks, and from the standard perspective `int32_t` and `int` are different types. So I am missing something here, but not sure what

Comment: @eugene 7.20 seems pretty clearly to be saying that `int32_t` and all the rest of stdint.h are typedef names for existing types, so they are not new types. What makes you think they are?

Comment: Note that "extended integer type" refers to something else. It's defined by the standard as well, but it has nothing to do with `stdint.h`.